Openssl static c++ - Visual Studio 2022
Download openssl, and compile it with nmake and with this configuration "perl Configure VC-WIN64A --prefix=C:\openssl\build --openssldir=C:\openssl" to be able to generate the .lib files and with this theme all very well compile everything without problems.


I have configured in the project properties the directories and paths of the libraries but every time I try to add a .h file to my code I get many errors as in the following images.
#define OPENSSL_API_COMPAT 30000
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include "openssl/idea.h"

#pragma comment (lib,"Crypt32.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "libssl.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "sqlite3.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "libcrypto.lib")

int main() {


    return 0;
}

Severity Code Description Project File Line Status Deleted Details
Error (live) E0757 variable "__owur" is not a Steal type name C:\Users\byron\OneDrive\Desktop\Steal\openssl\ssl.h 2143
Error (live) E0757 variable "__owur" is not a Steal type name C:\Users\byron\OneDrive\Desktop\Steal\openssl\ssl.h 1599
Error (live) E0757 variable "__owur" is not a Steal type name C:\Users\byron\OneDrive\Desktop\Steal\openssl\ssl.h 1600
Error (live) E0757 variable "__owur" is not a Steal type name C:\Users\byron\OneDrive\Desktop\Steal\openssl\ssl.h 1601
Error (live) E0757 Variable "__owur" is not a Steal type name C:\Users\byron\OneDrive\Desktop\Steal\openssl\ssl.h 1606
Error (live) E0757 Variable "__owur" is not a Steal type name C:\Users\byron\OneDrive\Desktop\Steal\openssl\ssl.h 1607
Error (live) E0757 Variable "__owur" is not a Steal type name C:\Users\byron\OneDrive\Desktop\Steal\openssl\ssl.h 1613
Error (live) E0757 Variable "__owur" is not a Steal type name a name of type Steal C:\Users\byron\OneDrive\Desktop\Steal\openssl\ssl.h 1632
Error (live) E0757 variable "__owur" is not a name of type Steal C:\Users\byron\OneDrive\Desktop\Steal\openssl\ssl.h 1633
Error (live) E0757 variable "__owur" is not a name of type Steal C:\Users\byron\OneDrive\Desktop\Steal\openssl\ssl.h 1655
Error (live) E0757 variable "__owur" is not a name of type Steal C:\Users\byron\OneDrive\Desktop\Steal\openssl\ssl.h 1656
Error (live) E0757 variable "__owur" is not a type name Steal C:\Users\byron\OneDrive\Desktop\Steal\openssl\ssl.h 1663
Error (live) E0757 variable "__owur" is not a type name Steal C:\Users\byron\OneDrive\Desktop\Steal\openssl\ssl.h 1714
Error (live) E0757 variable "__owur" is not a type name Steal C:\Users\byron\OneDrive\Desktop\Steal\openssl\ssl.h 1715
Error (live) E0757 variable "__owur" is not a type name Steal C:\Users\byron\OneDrive\Desktop\Steal\openssl\ssl.h 1747
Error (live) E0757 variable "__owur" is not a type name Steal C:\Users\byron\OneDrive\Desktop\Steal\openssl\ssl.h 1748
Error (live) E0757 variable "__owur" is not a type name Steal C:\Users\byron\OneDrive\Desktop\Steal\openssl\ssl.h 1764
Error (live) E0757 variable "__owur" is not a type name Steal C:\Users\byron\OneDrive\Desktop\Steal\openssl\ssl.h 1768
Error (live) E0757 variable "__owur" is not a type name Steal C:\Users\byron\OneDrive\Desktop\Steal\openssl\ssl.h 1776
Error (live) E0757 variable "__owur" is not a Steal type name C:\Users\byron\OneDrive\Desktop\Steal\openssl\ssl.h 1777
Error (live) E0757 variable "__owur" is not a Steal type name C:\Users\byron\OneDrive\Desktop\Steal\openssl\ssl.h 1814
Error (live) E0757 variable "__owur" is not a Steal type name C:\Users\byron\OneDrive\Desktop\Steal\openssl\ssl.h 1818
Error (live) E0757 variable "__owur" is not a Steal type name C:\Users\byron\OneDrive\Desktop\Steal\openssl\ssl.h 1902
Error (live) E0757 variable "__owur" is not a name of type Steal C:\Users\byron\OneDrive\Desktop\Steal\openssl\ssl.h 1903
Error (live) E0757 variable "__owur" is not a name of type Steal C:\Users\byron\OneDrive\Desktop\Steal\openssl\ssl.h 1992
Error (live) E0757 variable "__owur" is not a name of type Steal C:\Users\byron\OneDrive\Desktop\Steal\openssl\ssl.h 2087
Error (live) E0757 variable "__owur" is not a name of type Steal a Steal type name C:\Users\byron\OneDrive\Desktop\Steal\openssl\ssl.h 2089
Error (live) E0757 variable "__owur" is not a Steal type name C:\Users\byron\OneDrive\Desktop\Steal\openssl\ssl.h 2090
Error (live) E0757 variable "__owur" is not a Steal type name C:\Users\byron\OneDrive\Desktop\Steal\openssl\ssl.h 2091
Error (live) E0757 variable "__owur" is not a Steal type name C:\Users\byron\OneDrive\Desktop\Steal\openssl\ssl.h 2092
Error (live) E0757 variable "__owur" is not a type name Steal C:\Users\byron\OneDrive\Desktop\Steal\openssl\ssl.h 2124
Error (live) E0757 variable "__owur" is not a type name Steal C:\Users\byron\OneDrive\Desktop\Steal\openssl\ssl.h 2125
Error (live) E0757 variable "__owur" is not a type name Steal C:\Users\byron\OneDrive\Desktop\Steal\openssl\ssl.h 2139
Error (live) E0757 variable "__owur" is not a type name Steal C:\Users\byron\OneDrive\Desktop\Steal\openssl\ssl.h 2141
Error (live) E0757 variable "__owur" is not a type name Steal C:\Users\byron\OneDrive\Desktop\Steal\openssl\ssl.h 2149
Error (live) E0757 variable "__owur" is not a type name Steal C:\Users\byron\OneDrive\Desktop\Steal\openssl\ssl.h 2150
Error (live) E0757 variable "__owur" is not a type name Steal C:\Users\byron\OneDrive\Desktop\Steal\openssl\ssl.h 2171
Error (live) E0757 variable "__owur" is not a type name Steal C:\User
Error (active) E0065 expected ';' Steal C:\Users\byron\OneDrive\Desktop\Steal\openssl\ssl.h 1782
Error (active) E0065 expected ';' Steal C:\Users\byron\OneDrive\Desktop\Steal\openssl\ssl.h 1790
Error (active) E0065 expected ';' Steal C:\Users\byron\OneDrive\Desktop\Steal\openssl\ssl.h 1791
Error (active) E0065 expected ';' Steal C:\Users\byron\OneDrive\Desktop\Steal\openssl\ssl.h 1794
Error (active) E0065 expected ';' Steal C:\Users\byron\OneDrive\Desktop\Steal\openssl\ssl.h 1795
Error (live) E0065 expected ';' Steal C:\Users\byron\OneDrive\Desktop\Steal\openssl\ssl.h 1796
Error (live) E0065 expected ';' Steal C:\Users\byron\OneDrive\Desktop\Steal\openssl\ssl.h 1814
Error (live) E0065 expected ';' Steal C:\Users\byron\OneDrive\Desktop\Steal\openssl\ssl.h 1816
Error (live) E0065 expected ';' Steal C:\Users\byron\OneDrive\Desktop\Steal\openssl\ssl.h 1817
Error (live) E0065 expected ';' Steal C:\Users\byron\OneDrive\Desktop\Steal\openssl\ssl.h 1818
Error (live) E0065 expected ';' Steal C:\Users\byron\OneDrive\Desktop\Steal\openssl\ssl.h 1828
Error (live) E0065 expected ';' Steal C:\Users\byron\OneDrive\Desktop\Steal\openssl\ssl.h 1830
Error (live) E0065 expected ';' Steal C:\Users\byron\OneDrive\Desktop\Steal\openssl\ssl.h 1833
Error (live) E0065 expected ';' Steal C:\Users\byron\OneDrive\Desktop\Steal\openssl\ssl.h 1834
Error (live) E0065 expected ';' Steal C:\Users\byron\OneDrive\Desktop\Steal\openssl\ssl.h 1836
Error (live) E0065 expected ';' Steal C:\Users\byron\OneDrive\Desktop\Steal\openssl\ssl.h 1837
Error (live) E0065 expected ';' Steal C:\Users\byron\OneDrive\Desktop\Steal\openssl\ssl.h 1839
Error (live) E0065 expected ';' Steal C:\Users\byron\OneDrive\Desktop\Steal\openssl\ssl.h 1851
Error (live) E0065 expected ';' Steal C:\Users\byron\OneDrive\Desktop\Steal\openssl\ssl.h 1852
Error (live) E0065 expected ';' Steal C:\Users\byron\OneDrive\Desktop\Steal\openssl\ssl.h 1854
Error (live) E0065 expected ';' Steal C:\Users\byron\OneDrive\Desktop\Steal\openssl\ssl.h 1863
Error (live) E0065 expected ';' Steal C:\Users\byron\OneDrive\Desktop\Steal\openssl\ssl.h 1866
Error (live) E0065 expected ';' Steal C:\Users\byron\OneDrive\Desktop\Steal\openssl\ssl.h 1867
Error (live) E0065 expected ';' Steal C:\Users\byron\OneDrive\Desktop\Steal\openssl\ssl.h 1868
Error (live) E0065 expected ';' Steal C:\Users\byron\OneDrive\Desktop\Steal\openssl\ssl.h 1869
Error (live) E0065 expected ';' Steal C:\Users\byron\OneDrive\Desktop\Steal\openssl\ssl.h 1871
Error (live) E0065 expected ';' Steal C:\Users\byron\OneDrive\Desktop\Steal\openssl\ssl.h 1872
Error (live) E0065 expected ';' Steal C:\Users\byron\OneDrive\Desktop\Steal\openssl\ssl.h 1873
Error (live) E0065 expected ';' Steal C:\Users\byron\OneDrive\Desktop\Steal\openssl\ssl.h 1876
Error (live) E0065 expected ';' Steal C:\Users\byron\OneDrive\Desktop\Steal\openssl\ssl.h 1877
Error (live) E0065 expected ';' Steal C:\Users\byron\OneDrive\Desktop\Steal\openssl\ssl.h 1879
Error (live) E0065 expected ';' Steal C:\Users\byron\OneDrive\Desktop\Steal\openssl\ssl.h 1880
Error (live) E0065 expected ';' Steal C:\Users\byron\OneDrive\Desktop\Steal\openssl\ssl.h 1882
Error (live) E0065 expected ';' Steal C:\Users\byron\OneDrive\Desktop\Steal\openssl\ssl.h 1883
Error (live) E0065 expected ';' Steal C:\Users\byron\OneDrive\Desktop\Steal\openssl\ssl.h 1899
Error (live) E0065 expected ';' Steal C:\Users\byron\OneDrive\Desktop\Steal\openssl\ssl.h 1900
Error (live) E0065 expected ';' Steal C:\Users\byron\OneDrive\Desktop\Steal\openssl\ssl.h 1902
Error (live) E0065 expected ';' Steal C:\Users\byron\OneDrive\Desktop\Steal\openssl\ssl.h 1903
Error (live) E0065 expected ';' Steal C:\Users\byron\OneDrive\Desktop\Steal\openssl\ssl.h 1907
Error (live) E0065 expected ';' Steal C:\Users\byron\OneDrive\Desktop\Steal\openssl\ssl.h 1908
Error (live) E0065 expected ';' Steal C:\Users\byron\OneDrive\Desktop\Steal\openssl\ssl.h 1909
Error (active) E0065 expected ';' Steal C:\Users\byron\OneDrive\Desktop\Steal\openssl\ssl.h 1911
Error (active) E0065 expected ';' Steal C:\Users\byron\OneDrive\Desktop\Steal\openssl\ssl.h 1914
Error (active) E0065 expected ';' Steal C:\Users\byron\OneDrive\Desktop\Steal\openssl\ssl.h 1917
Error (active) E0065 expected ';' Steal C:\Users\byron\OneDrive\Desktop\Steal\openssl\ssl.h 1919
Error (active) E0065 expected ';' Steal C:\Users\byron\OneDrive\Desktop\Steal\openssl\ssl.h 1922
Error (active) E0065 expected ';' Steal C:\Users\byron\OneDrive\Desktop\Steal\openssl\ssl.h 1925
Error (active) E0065 expected ';' Steal C:\Users\byron\OneDrive
Error (active) E0065 expected ';' Steal C:\Users\byron\OneDrive\Desktop\Steal\openssl\ssl.h 1988
Error (active) E0065 expected ';' Steal C:\Users\byron\OneDrive\Desktop\Steal\openssl\ssl.h 1990
Error (active) E0065 expected ';' Steal C:\Users\byron\OneDrive\Desktop\Steal\openssl\ssl.h 1991
Error (active) E0065 expected ';' Steal C:\Users\byron\OneDrive\Desktop\Steal\openssl\ssl.h 1992
Error (active) E0065 expected ';' Steal C:\Users\byron\OneDrive\Desktop\Steal\openssl\ssl.h 1994
Error (active) E0065 expected ';' Steal C:\Users\byron\OneDrive\Desktop\Steal\openssl\ssl.h 1995
Error (active) E0065 expected ';' Steal C:\Users\byron\OneDrive\Desktop\Steal\openssl\ssl.h 1996
Error (active) E0065 expected ';' Steal C:\Users\byron\OneDrive\Desktop\Steal\openssl\ssl.h 2005
Error (active) E0065 expected ';' Steal C:\Users\byron\OneDrive\Desktop\Steal\openssl\ssl.h 2013
Error (live) E0065 expected ';' Steal C:\Users\byron\OneDrive\Desktop\Steal\openssl\ssl.h 2015
Error (live) E0065 expected ';' Steal C:\Users\byron\OneDrive\Desktop\Steal\openssl\ssl.h 2016
Error (live) E0065 expected ';' Steal C:\Users\byron\OneDrive\Desktop\Steal\openssl\ssl.h 2017
Error (live) E0065 expected ';' Steal C:\Users\byron\OneDrive\Desktop\Steal\openssl\ssl.h 2022
Error (active) E0065 expected ';' Steal C:\Users\byron\OneDrive\Desktop\Steal\openssl\ssl.h 2027
Error (active) E0065 expected ';' Steal C:\Users\byron\OneDrive\Desktop\Steal\openssl\ssl.h 2028
Error (active) E0065 expected ';' Steal C:\Users\byron\OneDrive\Desktop\Steal\openssl\ssl.h 2029
Error (active) E0065 expected ';' Steal C:\Users\byron\OneDrive\Desktop\Steal\openssl\ssl.h 2038
Error (active) E0065 expected ';' Steal C:\Users\byron\OneDrive\Desktop\Steal\openssl\ssl.h 2039
Error (active) E0065 expected ';' Steal C:\Users\byron\OneDrive\Desktop\Steal\openssl\ssl.h 2040
Error (active) E0065 expected ';' Steal C:\Users\byron\OneDrive\Desktop\Steal\openssl\ssl.h 2044
Error (active) E0065 expected ';' Steal C:\Users\byron\OneDrive\Desktop\Steal\openssl\ssl.h 2045
Error (active) E0065 expected ';' Steal C:\Users\byron\OneDrive\Desktop\Steal\openssl\ssl.h 2046
Error (active) E0065 expected ';' Steal C:\Users\byron\OneDrive\Desktop\Steal\openssl\ssl.h 2052
Error (active) E0065 expected ';' Steal C:\Users\byron\OneDrive\Desktop\Steal\openssl\ssl.h 2053
Error (active) E0065 expected ';' Steal C:\Users\byron\OneDrive\Desktop\Steal\openssl\ssl.h 2054
Error (active) E0065 expected ';' Steal C:\Users\byron\OneDrive\Desktop\Steal\openssl\ssl.h 2060
Error (active) E0065 expected ';' Steal C:\Users\byron\OneDrive\Desktop\Steal\openssl\ssl.h 2061
Error (active) E0065 expected ';' Steal C:\Users\byron\OneDrive\Desktop\Steal\openssl\ssl.h 2062
Error (active) E0065 expected ';' Steal C:\Users\byron\OneDrive\Desktop\Steal\openssl\ssl.h 2068
Error (live) E0065 expected ';' Steal C:\Users\byron\OneDrive\Desktop\Steal\openssl\ssl.h 2069
Error (live) E0065 expected ';' Steal C:\Users\byron\OneDrive\Desktop\Steal\openssl\ssl.h 2070
Error (live) E0065 expected ';' Steal C:\Users\byron\OneDrive\Desktop\Steal\openssl\ssl.h 2077
Error (live) E0065 expected ';' Steal C:\Users\byron\OneDrive\Desktop\Steal\openssl\ssl.h 2078
Error (active) E0065 expected ';' Steal C:\Users\byron\OneDrive\Desktop\Steal\openssl\ssl.h 2079
Error (active) E0065 expected ';' Steal C:\Users\byron\OneDrive\Desktop\Steal\openssl\ssl.h 2083
Error (active) E0065 expected ';' Steal C:\Users\byron\OneDrive\Desktop\Steal\openssl\ssl.h 2084
Error (active) E0065 expected ';' Steal C:\Users\byron\OneDrive\Desktop\Steal\openssl\ssl.h 2085
Error (live) E0065 expected ';' Steal C:\Users\byron\OneDrive\Desktop\Steal\openssl\ssl.h 2087
Error (live) E0065 expected ';' Steal C:\Users\byron\OneDrive\Desktop\Steal\openssl\ssl.h 2089
Error (live) E0065 expected ';' Steal C:\Users\byron\OneDrive\Desktop\Steal\openssl\ssl.h 2090
Error (live) E0065 expected ';' Steal C:\Users\byron\OneDrive\Desktop\Steal\openssl\ssl.h 2091
Error (live) E0065 expected ';' Steal C:\Users\byron\OneDrive\Desktop\Steal\openssl\ssl.h 2094
Error (live) E0065 expected ';' Steal C:\Users\byron\OneDrive\Desktop\Steal\openssl\ssl.h 2099
Error (live) E0065 expected ';' Steal C:\Users\byron\OneDrive\Desktop\Steal\openssl\ssl.h 2102
Error (live) E0065 expected ';' Steal C:\Users\byron\OneDrive\Desktop\Steal\openssl\ssl.h 2106
Error (active) E0065 expected ';' Steal C:\Users\byron\OneDrive\Desktop\Steal\openssl\ssl.h 2107
Error (active) E0065 expected ';' Steal C:\Users\byron\OneDrive\Desktop\Steal\openssl\ssl.h 2108
Error (active) E0065 expected ';' Steal C:\Users\byron\OneDrive\Desktop\Steal\openssl\ssl.h 2109
Error (active) E0065 expected ';' Steal C:\Users\byron\OneDrive\Desktop\Steal\openssl\ssl.h 2110
Error (active) E0065 expected ';' Steal C:\Users\byron\OneDrive\Desktop\Steal\openssl\ssl.h 2111
Error (active) E0065 expected ';' Steal C:\Users\byron\OneDrive\Desktop\Steal\openssl\ssl.h 2112
Error (active) E0065 expected ';'
Error (active) E1696 cannot open source file (error code "openssl/symhacks.h"). Steal C:\Users\byron\OneDrive\Desktop\Steal\openssl\ssl.h 42
Error (active) E1696 cannot open source file (error code "openssl/sslerr.h"). Steal C:\Users\byron\OneDrive\Desktop\Steal\openssl\ssl.h 44
Error (active) E1696 cannot open source file (error code "openssl/ssl3.h"). Steal C:\Users\byron\OneDrive\Desktop\Steal\openssl\ssl.h 984
Error (active) E1696 cannot open source file (error code "openssl/ssl2.h"). Steal C:\Users\byron\OneDrive\Desktop\Steal\openssl\ssl.h 983
Error (active) E1696 cannot open source file (error code "openssl/srtp.h"). Steal C:\Users\byron\OneDrive\Desktop\Steal\openssl\ssl.h 987
Error (active) E1696 cannot open source file (error code "openssl/safestack.h"). Steal C:\Users\byron\OneDrive\Desktop\Steal\openssl\ssl.h 41
Error (active) E1696 cannot open source file (error code "openssl/quic.h"). Steal C:\Users\byron\OneDrive\Desktop\Steal\openssl\ssl.h 988
Error (active) E1696 cannot open source file (error code "openssl/prov_ssl.h"). Steal C:\Users\byron\OneDrive\Desktop\Steal\openssl\ssl.h 45
Error (active) E1696 cannot open source file (error code "openssl/pem.h"). Steal C:\Users\byron\OneDrive\Desktop\Steal\openssl\ssl.h 37
Error (active) E1696 cannot open source file (error code "openssl/opensslconf.h"). Steal C:\Users\byron\OneDrive\Desktop\Steal\openssl\idea.h 19
Error (active) E1696 cannot open source file (error code "openssl/opensslconf.h"). Steal C:\Users\byron\OneDrive\Desktop\Steal\openssl\ssl.h 28
Error (active) E1696 cannot open source file (error code "openssl/macros.h"). Steal C:\Users\byron\OneDrive\Desktop\Steal\openssl\idea.h 14
Error (live) E1696 cannot open source file (error code "openssl/macros.h"). Steal C:\Users\byron\OneDrive\Desktop\Steal\openssl\ssl.h 21
Error (live) E1696 cannot open source file (error code "openssl/lhash.h"). Steal C:\Users\byron\OneDrive\Desktop\Steal\openssl\ssl.h 36
Error (live) E1696 cannot open source file (error code "openssl/hmac.h"). Steal C:\Users\byron\OneDrive\Desktop\Steal\openssl\ssl.h 38
Error (active) E1696 cannot open source file (error code "openssl/e_ostime.h"). Steal C:\Users\byron\OneDrive\Desktop\Steal\openssl\ssl.h 27
Error (active) E1696 cannot open source file (error code "openssl/e_os2.h"). Steal C:\Users\byron\OneDrive\Desktop\Steal\openssl\ssl.h 26
Error (active) E1696 cannot open source file (error code "openssl/dtls1.h"). Steal C:\Users\byron\OneDrive\Desktop\Steal\openssl\ssl.h 986
Error (active) E1696 cannot open source file (error code "openssl/ct.h"). Steal C:\Users\byron\OneDrive\Desktop\Steal\openssl\ssl.h 43
Error (active) E1696 cannot open source file (error code "openssl/crypto.h"). Steal C:\Users\byron\OneDrive\Desktop\Steal\openssl\ssl.h 33
Error (active) E1696 cannot open source file (error code "openssl/comp.h"). Steal C:\Users\byron\OneDrive\Desktop\Steal\openssl\ssl.h 29
Error (live) E1696 cannot open source file (error code "openssl/buffer.h"). Steal C:\Users\byron\OneDrive\Desktop\Steal\openssl\ssl.h 34
Error (live) E1696 cannot open source file (error code "openssl/bio.h"). Steal C:\Users\byron\OneDrive\Desktop\Steal\openssl\ssl.h 30
Error (live) E1696 cannot open source file (error code "openssl/async.h"). Steal C:\Users\byron\OneDrive\Desktop\Steal\openssl\ssl.h 39
Error C1083 Cannot open file include: 'openssl/macros.h': No such file or directory Steal C:\Users\byron\OneDrive\Desktop\Steal\openssl\idea.h 14
Error (active) E0070 Incomplete type "void" not allowed Steal C:\Users\byron\OneDrive\Desktop\Steal\openssl\ssl.h 659
Error (active) E0070 Incomplete type "void" not allowed Steal C:\Users\byron\OneDrive\Desktop\Steal\openssl\ssl.h 663
Error (active) E0070 incomplete type "void" not allowed Steal C:\Users\byron\OneDrive\Desktop\Steal\openssl\ssl.h 744
Error (active) E0070 incomplete type "void" not allowed Steal C:\Users\byron\OneDrive\Desktop\Steal\openssl\ssl.h 749
Error (active) E0070 incomplete type "void" not allowed Steal C:\Users\byron\OneDrive\Desktop\Steal\openssl\ssl.h 755
Error (active) E0070 incomplete type "void" not allowed Steal C:\Users\byron\OneDrive\Desktop\Steal\openssl\ssl.h 764
Error (active) E0070 Incomplete type "void" is not allowed Steal C:\Users\byron\OneDrive\Desktop\Steal\openssl\ssl.h 768
Error (active) E0070 Incomplete type "void" is not allowed Steal C:\Users\b



Those errors only come up when I try to compile the project and I get those errors even though I have almost no code.This is the simple structure of the project:


The errors should be copied from build output, translated to English and pasted in a code block.

I already made the errors in a code block

You did not. This a plain text not a text in a text block. This is a error list, not errors from the build output.

All the  "E" errors are from intellisense and should be ignored. Please show the compiler output

My guess would be that you've added ....\include\openssl to your include path rather than just ....\include
